# Try/Catch not catching exception

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to do java class loading. I'm using eclipse (luna) with 1.8.0_25 on a macos yosemite.

I'm using the following code in order to do it. It's working, until it reaches a class that has a dependency that isn't contained inside the jar that I'm loading classes from. Neither on the environment.

I'm not interested in this classes, so, it's safe to ignore then. So, I put it inside a try/catch and just log it.

But, when the exception occurs, the execution is canceled.

The exception (summarized) is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/runtime/internal/AroundClosure

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.runtime.internal.AroundClosure
```

It rises at the exact line that is inside the inner try/catch block.

Why? Shouldn't the try/catch just log it and move on?

```
URLClassLoader ucl = null;
try {
    URL url = Utils.getURIFromPath(jarFilePath).toURL();
    URL[] urls = new URL[] { url };
    ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
    for (String tmp : classes) {
        String clazz = tmp.substring(0, tmp.indexOf(".class")).replaceAll("/", ".");
        try {
            ucl.loadClass(clazz);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
} finally {
    if (ucl != null) {
        try {
            ucl.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about this on the stack trace? Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: Fix your classpath. You seem to be missing aspectj.jar in it.

Comment: Is that true? The line starts with `Exception in thread`

Comment: Come on, read the name of the class, and its javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NoClassDefFoundError` is an *Error*, not an `Exception`, you should **never**<sup>1</sup> try to `catch` an error, [as stated here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html), catching it won't help you.

Check your classpath and fix it.

<sup>1</sup> In some cases you might want to `catch` an error and handle it accordingly, as stated in the comments, maybe "*never*" is a little bit strong

Comment: Never is a strong word.

    try {
        array = new byte[bufsize];
    } catch (final OutOfMemoryError e) {
        // ...
    }
seems completely fine with me.

Answer (score 3):

Ok then try this:

```
catch (Throwable e) {
LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

Although using the above code will handle both Errors and Exceptions for you (both extend from `Throwable`), but it's not the right way to do it, only in very special cases do we handle errors using try-catch, errors are something we need to check in our code and resolve them.

Comment: Catching an error won't fix it. It will only hide it. The OP needs to fix its classpath. Catching Throwble is a bad practice, that won't fix anything.

Comment: @JB that't true man, but the guy seemed to just catch the error and not fix it the proper way, so i posted this solution, i think i should edit my answer and tell him about it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that one of the classes that you're using, probably one of the classes that you're trying to load with `loadClass`, has a *dependency* to classes from **AspectJ**, but the ClassLoader does not find the AspectJ classes. A possible solution is to **make sure that AspectJ is on your classpath** when you execute this.

It might also be that AspectJ already is on the classpath. If that's the case, it's just that your `URLClassLoader` doesn't know of your ClassPath. You might want to construct the `URLClassLoader` with a parent `ClassLoader` in place, like this:

```
ucl = new URLClassLoader(urls, getClass().getClassLoader());
```

The reason why the program doesn't just move on is that you're catching `Exception`. The hierarchy is `class Throwable`, `class Exception extends Throwable` and `class Error extends Throwable`, so `catch (Exception e)` will not catch `Error`. You might want to use `catch(Exception | NoClassDefFoundError e)` in this special case. Usually, catching Errors is not a good idea, but sometimes there are reasonable exceptions for errors like `NoClassDefFoundError`, `OutOfMemoryError` or `StackOverflowError`.